# Scaffold generated example fails with ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a weird issue with certain models not playing well with rails just because of their name (or so it seems to me). I tried to recreate the issue with a simple scaffold (i'd been doing it all by hand before), since I figured that way there would be less chance of user error, sure enough I got the same problem. I'm using Rails 4.2.3 and ruby 2.2.2p95 (ubuntu).

Try this (from within a new app):

```
rails generate scaffold Nursery name:string
```

Now go to the index (http://localhost:3000/nurseries) and click 'new nursery'. You'll get an error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Nurseries#new
```

Yet if I try and create something else, say...

```
rails generate scaffold Manuscript title:string
```

It just works.

Here's my (auto-generated) routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :manuscripts
  resources :nurseries
  resources :products
```

and here is the generated form partial for Nurseries (.../nurseries/_form.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(@nurseries), url: nurseries_path(@nurseries) do |f| %>
  <% if @nurseries.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@nurseries.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this nurseries from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>    
      <% @nurseries.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>    
        <li><%= message %></li>    
      <% end %>    
      </ul>    
    </div>    
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">    
    <%= f.submit %>    
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Can you rescue my sanity, please?

EDIT: more of the error:

```
 Showing /home/alex/ror-code/TestApp/app/views/nurseries/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"nurseries"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes | grep nursery`?

Comment: There should be some more part of the error you are missing. Please post it.

Comment: @Emu nothing. Honest.

Comment: @Pavan I've attached it to the bottom. It seems to be complaining about the missing 'id' field but at this stage, I don't think it has one (it's not been saved yet, right?) so I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: I've tested your code in my project and I receive the same error too. Very weird.

Comment: It seems like it is a naming issue. :(

Comment: @Pavan try creating a brand new project like I did and just using the scaffold generators as a sanity check. Weird indeed. I mean, I expect for me to make mistakes but for the generators to get something this simple, wrong, doesn't inspire me with confidence.

Comment: @Emu that was my thought too but I'd like to know why it happens and how to fix it, ideally. Seems like a bug in rails.

Comment: It returns same error after testing it in a new project. Could be a bug I guess.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to generate a scaffold for 'angry', it created an index for 'angries' but when I clicked on 'new angry' it actually worked. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a hunch which after testing proved to be correct :)
Rails (or just some parts of it, probably the part responsible with scaffolding) does not know how to pluralize **Nursery** correctly.

You can get around it by specifying an inflection rule:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'nursery', 'nurseries'
end
```

Destroy and then regenerate the Nursery scaffold, and it will work.

As a general rule of thumb, you should look into inflections when a bug occurs only for a specific controller/model/etc. name.

The pluralization of special words happens based on a list hard-coded in the framework. While this list is large, it's not 100% complete.

Comment: Fixed it, brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: I was thinking the same.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is not a bug. Rails (or just some parts of it most likely) does not know how to pluralize "Nursery" correctly.

Answer (score -4):

Error caused by link_to method.

```
 <%= link_to 'New Nurserie', new_nurserie_path %>
```

then new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@nurserie) do |f| %>
 --logic
<% end %>
```

Comment: Erm, I'm not sure what you mean @AmmY but thanks for trying. Did you try to follow my instructions on how to create the example projkect (above)?